# Display system resource usage from console application

Tags: c, windows, resources, console-application

I want to print the following details from a windows console application

1. Total RAM Available, total RAM used, RAM used by the application
2. Total CPU used, CPU used by the application
3. Total hard disk memory available, used memory size

I found lot of way to do this in online. Can any one tell me which is the best way to do it

Thanks in Advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total RAM available - [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx)

Total CPU used - [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Total hard disk memory available - [GetDiskFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How to calculate cpu usage from the GetProcessTimes. That function return only time value. From that how do i calculate the total cpu uages. Like that from GetProcessMemoryInfo function return some memory counters only. How do i calculate the total memory usage from that.

Comment: By searching i found that, memory usage can be calculated from PagefileUsage variable in PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS. So Memory Usage(kb) =(pMemCountr->PagefileUsage/1024). Is it correct?